Человек, который не поддерживает доминацию
Как назвать человека, который не поддерживает доминацию во взаимоотношениях между людьми (будь то в личной жизни, на работе или в обществе)?
Дисдоминантист, антидоминантист? Какой вариант верен?
Нужен ученый или учитель русского языка, так как я в интернете не могу найти данного определения.

Вы не поддерживаете право запятой стоять сразу после слова? В ожидании полезного ответа не навести ли порядок, будь то в тексте вопроса или в его шапке?

Такой человек называется анархист:

АНАРХИ́СТ, анархиста, муж.

Сторонник анархизма, член анархистской организации (полит.).
Человек, не подчиняющийся власти, авторитету, своевольный (разг.) Ушаков.


Даль:

АНАРХИЯ жен., греч. отсутствие в государстве или общине главы,
устроенного правления, силы, порядка; безвластие, безначалие,
многобоярщина, семибоярщина. Анархический, анархичный к анархии
относящийся. Анархист муж. анархистка жен. заступник, покровитель,
любитель безначалия, смут, крамол.
Анархия - так называется состояние общества, страны, государства, при
котором действовавшие законы попраны, самое понятие о законности
утрачено, всякая власть отвергнута. Являясь вслед за
революцией,подобное состояние не может длиться, не увлекая к
окончательной гибели данный политический организм; поэтому там, где
последний оказывается еще жизнеспособным, тотчас же после воцарения
анархии замечается реакция в пользу порядка и законности; последние
водворяются либо собственными усилиями благоразумной части населения,
либо временно потерявшим свой авторитет правительством, снова
становящимся во главе управления,благодаря содействию приверженных
порядку и спокойствию элементов населения, либо, наконец, каким-нибудь
другим лицом, сумевшим воспользоваться обстоятельствами, чтобы в
надлежащий момент стать у кормила правления и, водворив силою порядок,
вместо анархии установить,хотя временно, твердую самодержавную или
диктаторскую, деспотическую власть. Брокгауз и Эфрон.

Не, ну есть ещё всякие персонажи как либертарианцы - анархо-капиталисты.

Комментарии были перемещены в чат; пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь. Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с назначением комментариев. Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть ответами, размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

Бета-самец, Антидоминатор, Анархист, Активный пассив, Свободолюб

Если нужно слово, то пусть это будет антидоминист по образцу  анарх/ист, актив/ист, авантюр/ист.
Но по сути этот тот же анархист, как было уже сказано в первом ответе, но только в более обобщенном плане.
ДОМИНИРОВАТЬ [лат. dominari — господствовать] — господствовать, возвышаться над кем-л., преобладать.
Латинский корень сохраняется, слово удобно для произношения.
ОБ АНАРХИЗМЕ
Несколько слов об анархизме как общественном движении. Идея анархизма порочна в принципе, в ней нет возможности для реализации. Анархизм отрицает сам себя, еще не воплотившись в жизнь. О какой анархии можно говорить, если сами анархисты внутри собственных объединений подчиняются  кому-либо.
Другими словами, в любом обществе разделение на сильных и слабых, активных и пассивных неизбежно.  И это разделение необходимо, иначе не будет развития. Взаимодействие и борьба противоположностей по Гегелю лежит в основе любого движения, и в результате создается нечто новое и прогрессивное.

Комментарии были перемещены в чат; пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь. Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с назначением комментариев. Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть ответами, размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.
